# Blacks are somewhat grey in H.264 encoded quicktime

Tags: rendering

i'm currently using Quicktime, H.264 as my output. problem is the blacks are somewhat grey in the final output.

is there a better format for video quality?

thanks

Comment: One of the better compressed formats is Apple's Prores, which you can't create from within blender. But the blacks not being black is probably fault of the interpreter, namely the viewing application (I'm suspecting VLC). Have you tried replaying it in the Blenderplayer? Id advise you to create videos with ffmpeg if you are an advanced computer user, only rendering images with Blender and combining them into videos with ffmpeg.

Comment: Most likely the player you are using is not decoding correctly. Are you using the quicktime player in windows?

Comment: Read: https://vitrolite.wordpress.com/2010/12/31/quicktime_gamma_bug/

Comment: yes i'm using Quicktime to view the file. i'm trying to get an idea how it will look in the final product. online i.e. youtube, vimeo, etc...